# NearestNeighbors() returns sequence wrong

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am using `NearestNeighbors()` in the `sklean.neighbors` library to hand a `117*12` matrix. I am looking at the indices 2D array. The first element `indices[i][0]` is supposed be the node itself. However, at some element the sequence is replaced by its neighbors. I am wondering how I can prevent this from happening.

This is an example of the indices returned.

```
 [ 63 113  59  52  15]
 [ 64  35  14  12  66]
 [100  76  65  49  32]
 [ 66  12  14  35  64]
 [ 67   8 112  11  47]
 [ 68  92 104  80  66]
 [ 69  63  52  59 113]
 [ 70  60 107   7  27]
 [ 71  33  93  78  97]
 [ 72  45 116  30  99]
 [ 73  97   7  62  94]
 [ 74  46  90  79 115]
 [ 75 108  82  10  26]
 [100  76  65  49  32]
 [ 77   6  27  50   7]
 [ 78  93  97  62  73]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the samples at the given index are exactly equal. So in your case:

```
X[65] = X[76] = X[100]
```

assuming X to be the data.

When this is the case, the order is then decided internally. That order will be maintained as you can see :

```
...
[100  76  65  49  32]
...
...
[100  76  65  49  32]
...
```